# How to initialize void * to known datatype

Tags: c, void-pointers, msp430, iar

I've got an array of structs that holds a bunch of information that is will be a constant from compile time. I'm trying to initialize the array so that all of the information relevant to a particular variable is in one location. The problem I am running into is the datatype could be any number type for var_ptr or var_max (another member keeps track of the type for processing).

I am using void* for a pointer but I need some way of allocating memory and initializing it. See the commented out .var_max = &(23) below for an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
typedef enum{
  INT,
  CHAR,
  LONG,
  LONGLONG,
  FLOAT
} data_type_t;


typedef struct param_t param_t;


struct param_t{
  const char* name;                     //Text name of variable
  const void* var_ptr;                        //Pointer to variable
  const void* var_max;                  //Pointer to max limit of var_ptr, same datatype
  int (*p_func)(const param_t*, char *);//Function to process parameter variable
  const data_type_t data_type;          //Data type of 
};


int MinMax_handler(const param_t *, char *);

extern int Hours, Minutes, Seconds;
/******************Variables go here******************/
const param_t param[] =
{
  {.name = "DEV_RTC_HR", .var_ptr = &Hours, /*.var_max = &(23),*/ .p_func = &MinMax_handler, .data_type = INT},
  {.name = "DEV_RTC_MIN", .var_ptr = &Minutes, .p_func = &MinMax_handler, .data_type = INT},
  {.name = "DEV_RTC_SEC", .var_ptr = &Seconds, .p_func = &MinMax_handler, .data_type = INT}
};
/*****************************************************/
```

Commenting out .var_max = &(23) allows it to compile and seems to work fine.

It sounds like a union might work but would take up a lot more memory as most datatypes will be int (16bit) but I need to accommodate for a long long (64bit).

I'm need to keep this limited to C. The final version of this will be 50-150 array elements and automatically generated externally.

Comment: "No" is the first word when seeing the title.

Comment: For the member var_max, Is there anything preventing you from using a simple type such as int, or short?  Then you can just set the value in param_t param[].

Comment: One element of the struct array may be all char the next may be all long long. Needs to be type agnostic. And using all long long would eat up a lot of memory on a microcontroller.

Comment: @user3219864 Then the C answer is "can't be done." You want something the language does not support.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `.var_max = &(23)` you're trying to create a pointer to a literal value, which makes no sense

You can do one of two things:

1. Preallocate memory, place the value 23 there, and use that as your pointer
2. Assume that, when the size of the data fits in a `void *` (i.e., 64 bits or less, assumint you're on a 64 bit arch), then you can place the value directly in the pointer

   .var_max = (void *) 23

Comment: ok, but my answer still applies. If your data is 16 bit or less, you can store it directly in the pointer. Otherwise you'll need to allocate memory for it

Answer (score 0):

You need an object that the address-of operator can operate on, e.g.

```
long twentythree = 23L;

/* ... */, .var_max = &twentythree, /* ... */
```

Comment: Yeah, thats the obvious way of doing it but I am trying to figure out a way to put all of the parameters in one place (so its readable/editable by hand).

Comment: And yes the key here is I need an object to point to. I guess my question should have been is there a way to make the compiler generate the object automatically.